# Select where fecha actual

Tags: html, mysql, sql

Buen dia, realice un formulario que ,manda los datos a una base de datos, quiero hacer una consulta y que me traiga los datos cada dia pero no se como realizarlo, esto es lo que trate de hacer pero no me funciona, vi muchas paginas pero no logre comprender correctamente, espero puedan ayudarme

```
Select 
    Auditor, 
    Nombre_tablet,
    Fecha_Registro, 
    Tipouso 
from 
    shp_tablet_registros 
where 
    Tipouso='En carga' AND 
    Fecha_Registro=getdate() 
Order By Nombre_tablet ASC
```

formulario que se debe llenar:

```html
<tr>
                                                      <td><asp:Label ID="LblAuditor" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Auditor") %>' Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label></td>

<td><asp:Label ID="LblTablet" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Nombre_tablet") %>' Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label>/td>

<td><asp:Label ID="LabelFecha" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Fecha_Registro") %>' Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label></td>

<td><asp:Label ID="LblMovimiento" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Tipouso") %>' Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small"></asp:Label></td>
                                                     </tr>
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué es lo que no funciona exactamente? ¿Qué obtienes y qué esperas obtener? Si es posible muestra un ejemplo de los datos que estás manejando. Pulsa en [edit] para completar la pregunta.

Comment: hola! no me trae los datos del dia de hoy, no me trae nada de hecho,me trae los datos a menos de que ponga la fecha en especifico, pero es algo tedioso tener que estar haciendolo todos los dias

Comment: Pero, ¿hay datos con el día de hoy? ¿De qué tipo es la columna `Fecha_Registro` en tu tabla? Es importante saber cómo debe ser la comparación, si es sólo la fecha o si importa también la hora por ejemplo.

Comment: si tiene registros y como dijiste, es fecha y hora lo que contiene esa columna, almacena la fecha y la hora del registro

Comment: Ya, pero tú quieres, supongo, sólo los datos del día de hoy, sin importar la hora. Es que en este tipo de preguntas ayuda mucho que pongas un pequeño ejemplo de los datos, y que digas si la columna en la tabla es del tipo `DATE` o `DATETIME` o si, por desgracia, es `VARCHAR` en cuyo caso habría que hacer conversiones de tipos. Sin ver la realidad del problema sólo puede uno aventurarse en una respuesta, dando palos de ciego y adivinando cosas que debes decirnos tú, que tienes en mano el contexto.

Comment: si,muchas gracias, es tipo DATETIME ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la columna es `DATETIME` significa que comprende la fecha y la hora<sup>1</sup>, para obtener los registros de hoy, tendrías que verificar obteniendo sólo la fecha de la columna `Fecha_Registro` con la ayuda de [`DATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) y usar una función propia de MySQL para la fecha actual, como [`CURDATE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate).

Aquí te dejo un fiddle completo.

```
CREATE TABLE `shp_tablet_registros`
(
    `Auditor` VARCHAR(50), 
    `Nombre_tablet` VARCHAR(50),
    `Fecha_Registro` DATETIME, 
    `Tipouso` VARCHAR(50)
);
```

```
INSERT INTO `shp_tablet_registros` VALUES
('A1','T1','2023-05-12 00:00:00','En carga'),
('A2','T2','2023-05-12 00:00:10','En carga'),
('A3','T3','2023-05-13 01:00:00','En carga'),
('A4','T4','2023-05-15 02:00:00','En carga'),
('A5','T5','2023-05-15 03:00:08','No En carga'),
('A6','T6','2023-05-15 04:00:20','En carga'),
('A7','T7','2023-05-15 08:00:01','En carga');
```

> ```
> Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
> ```

```
SELECT 
    `Auditor`, 
    `Nombre_tablet`,
    `Fecha_Registro`, 
    `Tipouso` 
FROM 
    `shp_tablet_registros` 
WHERE 
    `Tipouso`='En carga' AND 
    DATE(`Fecha_Registro`)=CURDATE() 
ORDER BY
    `Nombre_tablet` ASC
```

| Auditor | Nombre_tablet | Fecha_Registro | Tipouso |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A4 | T4 | 2023-05-15 02:00:00 | En carga |
| A6 | T6 | 2023-05-15 04:00:20 | En carga |
| A7 | T7 | 2023-05-15 08:00:01 | En carga |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9wQWpjl6)

---

Si tienes dudas, pregunta en comentarios ... **Soy humano, no soy una IA**.

---

#### Notas

1. [Ver los tipos temporales en MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Comment: MUCHISIMAS GRACIAS!, por el tiempo y la paciencia, me ha funcionado

Comment: @Yaya.Z me alegro de que te haya servido. Me permito otra pequeña observación: considera normalizar tus datos, creando una tabla para los `Tipouso` y poniendo en `shp_tablet_registros` el id de cada tipo de uso. Las ventajas son al menos tres: posibilidad de índices más rápidos, porque usarás los IDs; ahorro de espacio, porque los VARCHAR suelen ocupar más espacio; minimización de errores, porque en el contexto actual cualquiera puede escribir cosas como `En carrga` o cosas por el estilo, mientras que si selecciona el IDs ese error no será posible.

Comment: claro!!,muchas gracias por la observacion  c:

Answer (score 1):

Buen día. Parece que estás utilizando SQL para realizar una consulta a tu base de datos y obtener los datos del día actual. Sin embargo, en el código que compartiste, estás utilizando la función getdate() en el filtro de la consulta, lo cual no es válido en el contexto de ASP.NET.

Para obtener la fecha actual en ASP.NET, puedes utilizar el objeto DateTime y su propiedad Today. Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
DateTime fechaActual = DateTime.Today;
```

Intenta asi para ver

Edit:

Luego, puedes modificar tu consulta SQL para utilizar la variable fechaActual en lugar de getdate().

Comment: muchas gracias!!;)